# Angular FormArray with searchbox binding

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to put an search-box inside an FormArray in Angular. I only managed to do using *select* element.

I have an array of place objects `[{'id':1, 'name':'p1'}, {'id':2, 'name':'p2'}, {'id':3, 'name':'p3'}]` that is the source for all dynamically created *select* elements.

My final result need to be a list with selected ids like `[1,3]`

It is working like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.placesArray = this.fb.array([]);
}
addPlace() {
    this.placesArray.push(new FormControl(''));
}
removePlace(i) {
    this.placesArray.removeAt(i);
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of placesArray.controls; let i=index">
  <div>
    <select [formControl]="placesArray.controls[i]">
      <option *ngFor="let place of places" [value]="place.id">
        {{place.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    <button (click)="removePlace(i)">remove</button>
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="addPlace()"></button>
```

When I click add, it adds a new input with data to select. When I select a option, it is bind to one `placesArray.value` index.

---

So, I want to replace the `<select>` element by a custom searchbox:

```html
<sarchbox [list]="places" (onChange)="selectedPlace($event)">
    <input [formControl]="placesArray.controls[i]">
</sarchbox>
```

This *searchbox* takes an array, shows `place.name` in a `<ul>` list and when clicked, it puts this value as the `<input>` value and sends back the item on onChange.

I'm unable to use this other component, it isn't binding with `place.id` in the final list `placesArray.value`

How would be good way to achieve this? Any thoughts are welcome.

Thanks.

Example: [stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-15qa3m](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-15qa3m)

Comment: please create stackblitz code so that we can take a look

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-15qa3m
I tried to simplify as much as I could. You can go to myform.component.html and take a look how is working with <select> then, comment it and uncomment <sarchbox>. When I select the value in the <li> it should put the ID in the final result